# How to compare two date and time in android

Tags: java, android

I have one problem is there. How to compare 2 date and time

```
enter code here
if(fromdate<=nowdt.now() && todate>= nowdt.now()){
////

}
```

Answer (score 11):

The java.util.Date object contains methods .before(), .after and .equals() for comparing dates.

```
if((fromdate.before(nowDt) || fromDate.equals(nowDt)) 
    && ((todate.after(nowDt) || toDate.equals(nowDt))
////

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function to compare two date and time:

```
public static int compareTwoDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
        if (date1 != null && date2 != null) {
            int retVal = date1.compareTo(date2);

            if (retVal > 0)
                return 1; // date1 is greatet than date2
            else if (retVal == 0) // both dates r equal
                return 0;

        }
        return -1; // date1 is less than date2
    }
```

You can use it where you want to. Result will be > 0 if date1 > date2, = 0 if date1 = date2, < 0 if date1 < date2. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old answer, but why not just return date1.compareTo(date2)? Wouldn't that yield the same results?

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `Joda Time library` to do this....

**Eg:**

```
Date ds = new Date();
DateTime d = new DateTime(ds);

DateTime e = new DateTime(2012,12,07, 0, 0);
System.out.println(d.isEqual(e));


System.out.println(d.toDateMidnight().isEqual(e.toDateMidnight()));
```

**///////////////////////////// OR**

```
System.out.println(d.withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(e.withTimeAtStartOfDay()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out to find time difference

```
  Calendar Day = Calendar.getInstance();
  Day.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
  Day.set(Calendar.MONTH,7); 
  Day.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1985);

  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

  long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - Day.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
long nowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(fromdate.getTime() <= nowTime && nowTime <= todate.getTime()) {
```

or you can write

```
Date nowDate = new Date();
if(fromdate.compareTo(nowDate) * nowDate.compareTo(todate) >= 0) {
```

or

```
if(!fromdate.after(nowDate) && !todate.before(nowDate))
```

Answer (score 0):

use this answer

```
if((options.FromDate.before(now_Date)||options.FromDate.equals(now_Date)) && (options.ToDate.after(now_Date)|| options.ToDt.equals(now_Date)) ){

do some processs........
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain why?